# How to calculate sum of two polynomials?

Tags: python, python-3.x, polynomials

For instance 3x^4 - 17x^2 - 3x + 5.  Each term of the polynomial can be represented as a pair of integers (coefficient,exponent).  The polynomial itself is then a list of such pairs like
`[(3,4), (-17,2), (-3,1), (5,0)]` for the polynomial as shown.

Zero polynomial, 0, is represented as the empty list `[]`, since it has no terms with nonzero coefficients.

I want to write two functions to add and multiply two input polynomials with the same representation of tuple (coefficient, exponent):

1. `addpoly(p1, p2)`
2. `multpoly(p1, p2)`

Test Cases:

- `addpoly([(4,3),(3,0)], [(-4,3),(2,1)])` 
  should give `[(2, 1),(3, 0)]`
- `addpoly([(2,1)],[(-2,1)])` 
  should give `[]`
- `multpoly([(1,1),(-1,0)], [(1,2),(1,1),(1,0)])` 
  should give `[(1, 3),(-1, 0)]`

Here is something that I started with but got completely struck!

```
def addpoly(p1, p2):
    (coeff1, exp1) = p1
    (coeff2, exp2) = p2
    if exp1 == exp2:
        coeff3 = coeff1 + coeff2
```

Comment: You must first find or work out the algorithm (math or natural language) for arithmetic on sparse representations of polynomials with one indefinite.  Until then, this is not a programming question.

Comment: you need to put a bit more effort into this if you want some help.  at least make your function return something.

Comment: It might be better to make each polynomial a dictionary consisting of exponent key mapping to the associated coefficient. So the sample one in your question would become: `{4: 3, 2: 17, 1: 3, 0: 5}`. With such a data structure it would become relatively easy to access the terms (or check for their existence) in each polynomial passed to the functions. Beyond that, it just a matter of implementing what you would do if you were doing it by hand with a pencil and some paper.

Comment: `collections.Counter` makes `addpoly` a trivial task

Comment: Unless you expect your polynomials to be very sparse and very high degree, you are almost certainly better off representing them as a list of coefficients with the first entry being the coefficient of x^0, the second as the coefficient of x^1, etc. This way you may just add entry-wise. The result has length equal to the length of the longest polynomial. And its degree is easily inferred from the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057546/how-to-calculate-sum-of-two-polynomials#comment65465088_39057546) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057546/how-to-calculate-sum-of-two-polynomials#comment65466242_39057546), it is much simpler to represent polynomials as [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of exponents.

In Python, the closest thing to a multiset is the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) data structure.  Using a `Counter` (or even just a plain dictionary) that maps exponents to coefficients will automatically coalesce entries with the same exponent, just as you'd expect when writing a simplified polynomial.

You can perform operations using a `Counter`, and then convert back to your list of pairs representation when finished using a function like this:

```
def counter_to_poly(c):
    p = [(coeff, exp) for exp, coeff in c.items() if coeff != 0]
    # sort by exponents in descending order
    p.sort(key = lambda pair: pair[1], reverse = True)
    return p
```

To add polynomials, you group together like-exponents and sum their coefficients.

```
def addpoly(p, q):
    r = collections.Counter()

    for coeff, exp in (p + q):
        r[exp] += coeff

    return counter_to_poly(r)
```

(In fact, if you were to stick with the Counter representation throughout, you could just `return p + q`).

To multiply polynomials, you multiply each term from one polynomial pairwise with every term from the other. And furthermore, to multiply terms, you add exponents and multiply coefficients.

```
def mulpoly(p, q):
    r = collections.Counter()

    for (c1, e1), (c2, e2) in itertools.product(p, q):
        r[e1 + e2] += c1 * c2

    return counter_to_poly(r)
```

Answer (score 1):

This python code worked for me,hope this works for u too...

## Addition func

```
def addpoly(p1,p2):
i=0
su=0
j=0
c=[]
if len(p1)==0:
    #if p1 empty
    return p2
if len(p2)==0:
    #if p2 is empty
    return p1
while i<len(p1) and j<len(p2):
    if int(p1[i][1])==int(p2[j][1]):
        su=p1[i][0]+p2[j][0]
        if su !=0:
            c.append((su,p1[i][1]))
        i=i+1
        j=j+1
    elif p1[i][1]>p2[j][1]:
        c.append((p1[i]))
        i=i+1
    elif p1[i][1]<p2[j][1]:
        c.append((p2[j]))
        j=j+1
if p1[i:]!=[]:
    for k in p1[i:]:
        c.append(k)
if p2[j:]!=[]:
    for k in p2[j:]:
        c.append(k)
return c
```

## Multiply func

```
def multipoly(p1,p2):
p=[]
s=0
for i in p1:
    c=[]
    for j in p2:
        s=i[0]*j[0]
        e=i[1]+j[1]
        c.append((s,e))
    p=addpoly(c,p)
return p
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution but I'm unsure that it's optimized!

```
    def addpoly(p1,p2):
        for i in range(len(p1)):
            for item in p2:
                if p1[i][1] == item[1]:
                    p1[i] = ((p1[i][0] + item[0]),p1[i][1])
                    p2.remove(item)
        p3 = p1 + p2
        for item in (p3):
            if item[0] == 0:
                p3.remove(item)
        return sorted(p3)
```

and the second one:-

```
    def multpoly(p1,p2):
        for i in range(len(p1)):
            for item in p2:
                p1[i] = ((p1[i][0] * item[0]), (p1[i][1] + item[1]))
                p2.remove(item)
        return p1
```