# Python program to multiply two polynomial where each term of the polynomial is represented as a pair of integers (coefficient, exponent)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

fuction takes two list(having tuples as values) as input
i got in my mind following algorithm to write code for this, but to write it properly.

-->firstly make required no. of dictionary to store coefficient of each power is multiplied with all coefficient of polynomial p2.

then all dictionary coefficient are added which having same power.

```
def multpoly(p1,p2):

    dp1=dict(map(reversed, p1))
    dp2=dict(map(reversed, p2))
    kdp1=list(dp1.keys())
    kdp2=list(dp2.keys())

    rslt={}
    if len(kdp1)>=len(kdp2): 
      kd1=kdp1
      kd2=kdp2
    elif len(kdp1)<len(kdp2):
      kd1=kdp2
      kd2=kdp1
    for n in kd2:
      for m in kd1:
        rslt[n]={m:0}
        if len(dp1)<=len(dp2):
          rslt[n][m+n]=rslt[n][m+n] + dp1[n]*dp2[m]
        elif len(dp1)>len(dp2):
          rslt[n][m+n]=rslt[n][m+n] + dp2[n]*dp1[m]
    return(rslt)
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Not clear to me what you're asking or what your problem is exactly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39057546/how-to-calculate-sum-of-two-polynomials/39058521#39058521) question?

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38979149/235698), and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39066275/235698).  Looks like a lot of people want homework help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a function to multiply two polynomials and return the result. In the future, try and post a specific question. Here is code that will work for you:

```
def multiply_terms(term_1, term_2):
    new_c = term_1[0] * term_2[0]
    new_e = term_1[1] + term_2[1]
    return (new_c, new_e)


def multpoly(p1, p2):
    """
    @params p1,p2 are lists of tuples where each tuple represents a pair of term coefficient and exponent
    """
    # multiply terms
    result_poly = []
    for term_1 in p1:
        for term_2 in p2:
            result_poly.append(multiply_terms(term_1, term_2))
    # collect like terms
    collected_terms = []
    exps = [term[1] for term in result_poly]
    for e in exps:
        count = 0
        for term in result_poly:
            if term[1] == e:
                count += term[0]
        collected_terms.append((count, e))
    return collected_terms
```

Note however, there are definitely much better ways to represent these polynomials such that the multiplication is faster and easier to code. Your idea with the dict is slightly better but still messy. You could use a list where the index represents the exponent and the value represents the coefficient. For ex. you could represent `2x^4 + 3x + 1` as `[1, 3, 0, 0, 2]`.